# Complement of a Regular set?

Tags: general-topology

I have came across this exercise in my textbook.It says that a open set is called" regular" if the interior of the sets closure is the set itself.
A close set is regular if the closure of its interior is itself.
How can I show that the complement of a regular open(or close) set is still regular?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A$ be a regular open set so that $A=(\overline {A})^{0}$. Then $A^{c}=((\overline {A})^{0})^{c}$. Use the following general fact to complete the proof: for any sets $E$ and $F$ we have  $(E^{0})^{c}=\overline {E^{c}}$ and $(\overline {F})^{c}=(F^{c})^{0}$. [ Notations: $A^{0}$ is the interior of $A$ and the $\overline {A}$ is the closure of $A$.

Comment: Oops I forget to explain the situation for closed sets.

Comment: Thanks!That was brilliant and helpful!